# Fluent NHibernate do not load linked collection

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I've got two simple entities:

```
public class Post {
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string Title {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<Comment> {get;set;}
}
```

and

```
public class Comment {
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string Text {get;set;}
    public virtual Post Post {get;set;}
}
```

Corresponding mappings looks like:

```
HasMany(x => x.Comment).LazyLoad();
References(x => x.Post).Not.LazyLoad();
```

My goal is to load Comments in Posts only if I want it and don't load Comments otherwise.  something like that:

```
var posts = session.QueryOver<Post>().ToList() // load posts without comments
var posts = session.QueryOver<Post>().FetchMany(x => x.Comments).ToList(); // load posts with comments
```

I'm using FluentNHibernate 2.0.1 and NHibernate 4 with Postgres 9.2

Comment: it should work as is, dont see any issues with the above code

Comment: Maybe u could help - shall I use in this case
.Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Always())
in configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the lazy load convention works mostly on list's only, I have tried my fair share of troubles when I tried to use it on non-collection child elements.

So yes, you can use `.Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Always())` but that should be preferred for collections only